# Is there a way for WebGL to provide a hint for which ANGLE backend to use?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, directx, nvidia, angle

I have a web app that uses WebGL for 3D rendering which renders fine on Linux, but not on several Windows 10 systems (chrome, edge, and firefox). It appears that when my NVidia GPU is being used, the GL context is lost almost immediately. When the integrated Intel GPU is used, it renders, but is unacceptably slow.

In Chrome 94, if I change the "#use-angle" flag from D3D11 to OpenGL, it runs perfectly.

Is there way in my web application to provide a hint about which Angle backend should be preferred by the browser?

Or is my only path forward (without telling users to toggle an experimental browser flag) to try to figure out what part of my app/shaders D3D11 is choking on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way in my web application to provide a hint about which Angle backend should be preferred by the browser?

No

> Or is my only path forward (without telling users to toggle an experimental browser flag) to try to figure out what part of my app/shaders D3D11 is choking on?

Yes

Maybe you're trying to compile a ton of heavy shaders(e.g. shaders with nested loops) at the same time?